# CC.NET prevent certain folders from being retrieved on SVN build

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to configure a selection of folders that will not be retrieved from SVN when running a build under CC.NET?

I am releasing from my Trunk directory and there are folders within the Trunk folder that I do not want to retrieve as they contain large files that are not required for the build, we just keep them in SVN for tracking purposes. For example,

Trunk

- Folder 1
- Folder 2 - don't want to include this one on an SVN update
- Folder 3

Our other build servers use SourceGear Vault and you can Cloak a folder given a user account, which means it will not be retrieved from a "Get Latest" request. This is how we did it for those environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim, not sure if you still have this issue as its a few months later; however, I resolved this issue with multiple SourceControl blocks. You can build out the same directory structure and only check out what is needed. Although not ideal, it does resolve this issue.

Comment: As you say : not Ideal but it does resolve the issue. +1 to have thought of it.

Comment: I never pursued this in the end but your solution does resolve the issue. Don't like the sound of lots of CC projects though! :D

Comment: Tim Peel; its still one project, you just use the "<sourcecontrol type="multi">" block to specify different folders. Please see the following for more information; http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Multi+Source+Control+Block

Answer (score 0):

Subversion itself supports [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) - not sure if you can make CC.NET use those, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with cc.net.
You have a filtered source control block but it filters only for build triggers, not for retrieving.

I think the "good" way would be to make the Folder 2 either a level up or an [external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) because if it's not used for the build, it has nothing to do in the code directory.

Comment: Ben, just because a folder isn't used for a given solution doesn't mean it’s not used for another solution. If you have a folder of shared components and you only want to check out 2 folders out of all the shared components?